# How to retain current current pagination page number when webpage is refreshed?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I have simple pagination included in my homepage in order to display the latest news/images  from my server. The pagination is working fine but when i try to move to other page number example page 2, the page loads but after refreshing it goes back again to page 1. I am new to PHP , Ajax and Jquery so I can't figure out where to solve this problem. Here are my codes:

pagination.php

```
    <?php
function paginate($reload, $page, $tpages, $adjacents) {
$prevlabel = "&lsaquo; Prev";
$nextlabel = "Next &rsaquo;";
$out = '<div class="pagin page_style">';
// previous label
if($page==1) {
    $out.= "<span>$prevlabel</span>";
} else if($page==2) {
    $out.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load(1)'>$prevlabel</a>";
}else {
    $out.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load(".($page-1).")'>$prevlabel</a>";

}   
// first label
if($page>($adjacents+1)) {
    $out.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load(1)'>1</a>";
}
// interval
if($page>($adjacents+2)) {
    $out.= "...\n";
}
// pages
$pmin = ($page>$adjacents) ? ($page-$adjacents) : 1;
$pmax = ($page<($tpages-$adjacents)) ? ($page+$adjacents) : $tpages;
for($i=$pmin; $i<=$pmax; $i++) {
    if($i==$page) {
        $out.= "<span class='current'>$i</span>";
    }else if($i==1) {
        $out.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load(1)'>$i</a>";
    }else {
        $out.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load(".$i.")'>$i</a>";
    }
}
// interval
if($page<($tpages-$adjacents-1)) {
    $out.= "...\n";
}
// last
if($page<($tpages-$adjacents)) {
    $out.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load($tpages)'>$tpages</a>";
}
// next
if($page<$tpages) {
    $out.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load(".($page+1).")'>$nextlabel</a>";
}else {
    $out.= "<span>$nextlabel</span>";
}
$out.= "</div>";
return $out;
}
?>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////

Home.php

```
        <?php session_start(); ?>
    <?php 
    $action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
    if($action == 'ajax'){
    /* Connect To Database*/
    $dbname = 'banaue.com';
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldn't make connection.");
    $db = mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

    include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
    //pagination variables
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
    $per_page = 1; //how many records you want to show
    $adjacents  = 5; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    //Count the total number of row in your table*/
    $count_query   = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(title) AS numrows FROM news");
    $row     = mysql_fetch_array($count_query);
    $numrows = $row['numrows'];
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
    $reload = 'Home.php';
    //main query to fetch the data
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date_posted LIMIT $offset,$per_page");
    //loop through fetched data
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $id = $test['title'];   
    echo "<div class='content' stye=margin-bottom: 20px;>";
    echo'<div class="img_content" ><img src='.$test['img_path'].' style=height:520px;width:100%;></div>';
                echo"<p class=para_news2 style=margin-left:10px;><font color='#336699'>" .$test['title']."</p></font><br /><br />";
                echo"<p class=para_news4 style=margin-left:10px;width:100%;><img src='images/user.gif'>&nbspStory By: <font color='lavander'>" .$test['author']."</font></p>";
                echo"<p class=para_news4 style=margin-left:10px;width:100%;><img src='images/calendar.gif'>&nbspDate Posted: <font color='red'>". $test['date_posted']. "</font></p>";
                echo"<p class=para_news3 style=margin-left:10px;width:100%;><img src='images/comments.gif'>&nbsp<font color='black'>". $test['intro']. "</font></p><br>";
                echo"<a href ='news.php?title=$id'><font style='float:right;margin-right:10px;background:url(images/bg_header.jpg);padding:2px;'>Read more ...</a><br>";
    echo        "</div>";
}
echo paginate($reload, $page, $total_pages, $adjacents);

} else{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><!-- Head declaration -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        load(1);
    });
    function load(page){
        $("#loader").fadeIn('slow');
        $.ajax({
            url:'Home.php?action=ajax&page='+page,
            success:function(data){
                $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                $("#loader").fadeOut('slow');
            }
        })
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Body Content -->
<div class="main_body" style="height:auto;">
<!-- Top Stories Query-->
<div class="outer_div">
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<?php }?>
```

Please help me with this problem so that i can move on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a cookie to store the current pagination position in the clients web browser and read it back when creating the page, to start pagination from last position.

Something like this

```
setcookie('pagination_pos',$pagination_pos,time() + 86400); // 86400 = expire after 1 day
```

and then read it back

```
echo 'Current position '($_COOKIE['pagination_pos']!='' ? $_COOKIE['pagination_pos'] : 0);
```

this will read the current position from the cookie, if no cookie is there it falls back to 0.

Okay as you requested on how to use it in your code, I made a simple example function you can use in your code:

```
function getPaginationPos(){
if (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page'])){
    setcookie('pagination_pos',$_REQUEST['page'],time() + 86400);
    return $_REQUEST['page'];
} else {
    return ($_COOKIE['pagination_pos']!='' ? $_COOKIE['pagination_pos'] : 1);
}

}
```

this will check if there is a "page" variable in the request and if so it will store the position as a cookie. If no "page" variable is in the request it will check if there is a cookie or return 1.

If I understand your code right you have to replace this line

```
$page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
```

with

```
$page = getPaginationPos();
```

I see another problem in the javascript "load" function where you force page 1 on reload

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    load(1);
});
```

you can try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    load();
});
```

add also a check for the page variable to the javascript function, to handle the case if page is not set.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $( document ).ready(function() {
         load()
      });

      function load(page){
      if (typeof page === 'undefined') {
        page = ''
      } else{
        page = '&page='+page
      }
      $("#loader").fadeIn('slow');
      $.ajax({
        url:'Home.php?action=ajax'+page,
        success:function(data){
        $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
        $("#loader").fadeOut('slow');
        }
      })
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample line on how to implement it and where exactly to insert it. Im sorry to ask this silly request but I really have no idea to do it..I never used cookies...can i use session instead a cookie?

Comment: I've just added an example function to show how you can use it in your code.

Comment: Sir @manuel.I tried to change the line you quoted and place the function inside <head> but i got error but when i place the function just above this line $page = getPaginationPos(); no error but still returning to page 1....you might think i'm really trying hard to do this but im sorry im really confused...lol.

Comment: Are there any needed settings on my browser to accept cookies or none at all to:@Manuel?

Comment: Still not working sir @manuel My pagination uses a javascript script which i forgot to include on my post. It is very long line...

Comment: most modern browsers allow cookie from the same domain by default. so this should not be an issue. otherwise you can store session information on the server, but this would also require to have a cookie on the client side to match the session. if it comes to a complete reload of the page a cookie is actually the only way to recognise a client. the error was in the java script, if page was not set (on initial load) it sends "undefined" as content to the server. So if we override this, it works.

Comment: Good morning here in the Philippines...I had been expecting a further answer from you sir @manuel this morning when i opened my laptop and Yes I tried changing my Load function and amazingly it worked...I felt guilty by not solving this by myself but I have to because I can't move on if i can't solve this...Anyways, Thank very much sir...

Comment: I have to confirm another thing Sir @manuel ..Is it right to put the function getPaginationPos() just right before the line $page = getPaginationPos(); inside the PHP code on top of Home.php or is it on the wrong place? I tried to place it inside <head></head> but i got errors for undefined variables so i placed it there instead and it's working fine...I have to verify this to you because i might encounter another problem about it as i proceed...Thanks.

Comment: @manuel I got an error on line 17 for undefined variable 'pagination_pos' when the webpage loads for the 1st time..but the error fades away when I tried to click on another page of the pagination...I placed the function getPaginationPos() code just before this line $page = getPaginationPos();....Where am i getting the error..where is the right place to insert the function you gave me...

Comment: Hi, I've put the function on the end of the pagination.php file. But you can put it everywhere before the function call, but it has to be inside a php code segment (<?PHP ...?>)

Comment: About the issue with "pagination_pos" undefined. I did not declare a variable with this name. This is a string, as content for the cookie I reuse the "page" variable, which was already there before. Maybe you missed something while copy the code?

Answer (score 0):

based on Sir Manuel's code, if you don't want to store your variable to be stored in cookies you can try to put it in session variable.

change this line:

```
function getPaginationPos(){
     if (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page'])){
          setcookie('pagination_pos',$_REQUEST['page'],time() + 86400);
          return $_REQUEST['page'];
     } else {
          return ($_COOKIE['pagination_pos']!='' ? $_COOKIE['pagination_pos'] : 1);
     }

}
```

into this:

```
function getPaginationPos(){
    if (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page'])){         
        $_SESSION['pages'] = $_REQUEST['page'];
        return $_REQUEST['page'];
    } else {
        return $_SESSION['pages'];
    }
}
```

and this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    load();
});
```

into this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      load(<?php print $_SESSION['pages']; ?>);
 });
```